# Set homepage to top sites

Tags: microsoft-edge

Right now, when I'm done with a tab and want to reuse it, I have to close it and open a new one to see the top sites page. (I have new tabs set to open the top sites page.)

I have the home button enabled, so I'm wondering if there's a way to set the home page to the top sites page.

If possible, how is it done?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but usually its about:tabs. Set that as the home page and you're done.

Comment: @LPChip That's it, just tested it on Edge. You should post it as an answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Made an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most browsers, including Edge, `about:tabs` shows the top visited sites.

If you set this as your homepage, you're set.

Comment: Most browsers?  Not Firefox.

Comment: So, Most browsers is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

To set your home to frequent pages, open setting, click `View advanced settings` and change the text box under `show the home button` to `about:tabs`.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Why not? Edge doesn't show a home button by default, so the OP has to activate the home button, and the home page is set to about:start.

Comment: As stated in the second paragraph of the questions: *"I have the home button enabled"*. He already has that done, but by default it sets the homepage to `about:start` which shows Microsoft's idea of interesting news instead of the top sites. And I can confirm setting it to `about:tabs` instead shows the requested page.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question then. Thanks I'll edit my response.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to open the top sites page when clicking the home button by doing the following:
 Click the three dots -> Settings -> View advanced settings -> under the "Show the home button" checkbox, there is a dropdown list, from that list choose "New tab page".

Hope it helps!